# Sorting a string matrix java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, matrix

Hello guys I have written a code  https://pastebin.com/U3G1yBip

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PlayerRanking {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String[][] player=new String[100000][5];
    String[][] findArray=new String[7][2];
    String[] sorted=new String[100000];
    int count=0;
    int index=0;
    while(true){
        String[] tokens = in.readLine().split(" ");
        if(tokens[0].equals("add")){
            player[index][0]=tokens[1];//PLAYER_NAME 
            player[index][1]=tokens[2] ;//PLAYER_TYPE 
            player[index][2]=tokens[3] ;//PLAYER_AGE 
            if(count==0){
                player[index][3]=tokens[4];//PAYER_POSITION
                System.out.println("Added player "+tokens[1]+" to position "+ tokens[4]);
                count++;
                index++;
            }else{ 
            //player[index][3]=
                if(isPosAvailable(player,(Integer.parseInt(tokens[4])),count)){
                    player=(UpdateAndAdd(player,Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]),count,index)).clone();
                    //System.out.println("Its  available");
                    System.out.println("Added player "+tokens[1]+" to position "+ tokens[4]);
                    count++;
                    index++;
                }else{
                    //System.out.println("Its not available");
                    player=(UpdateAndAdd(player,Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]),count,index)).clone();
                    System.out.println("Added player "+tokens[1]+" to position "+ tokens[4]);
                    count++;
                    index++;
                }
                //PAYER_POSITION 
            }
        }
        if(tokens[0].equals("find")){
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
                System.out.println(getName(player,i)+" "+getType(player,i)+" "+getAge(player,i)+" "+getPos(player,i));
            }
            findArray=sort(player,count,index);
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
                System.out.println(getName(findArray,i)+" "+getType(findArray,i)+" "+getAge(findArray,i)+" "+getPos(findArray,i));
            }
            System.out.println(getIndexPos(player,"1",count));

        }
        if(tokens[0].equals("ranklist")){
            int ranklistA=Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            int ranklistB=Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
            for(int i=(ranklistA-1);i<(ranklistB-1);i++){
                System.out.println(player[i][3]);
            }
        }
        if(tokens[0].equals("end")){
            break;
        }
    }
}
public static boolean isPosAvailable(String [][] rankaddarray,int pos,int count){
    boolean isAvbl=false;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        if((rankaddarray[i][3]).equals(String.valueOf(pos))){
            isAvbl=false;
            break;
        }else{
            isAvbl=true;
        }
    }
    return isAvbl;
}
public static String [][] UpdateAndAdd(String [][] rankaddarray,int pos,int count, int index){
    int a = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        if((Integer.parseInt(rankaddarray[i][3]))>=pos){
            rankaddarray[i][3]=String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(rankaddarray[i][3]))+ a);
        }else{continue;}
    }
    rankaddarray[index][3]=String.valueOf(pos);
    return rankaddarray;
}
public static String [][] sort(String [][] data,int count, int index){
    for(int k=1;k<count;k++){
        String[][] current=data[k][*];
        int j=k;
        while(j>0 && data[j-1]>current){
            data[j]=data[j-1];
            j--;
        }
        data[j]=current;
    }
    return data;
}


public static String getName(String[][] data,int instance){
    String pos=data[instance][0];
    return pos;
}
public static String getType(String[][] data,int instance){
    String pos=data[instance][1];
    return pos;
}
public static String getAge(String[][] data,int instance){
    String pos=data[instance][2];
    return pos;
}
public static String getPos(String[][] data,int instance){
    String pos=data[instance][3];
    return pos;
}
public static int getIndexPos(String[][] data,String pos, int count){
    int index=0;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
         if((data[i][3]).equals(pos)){
             index=i;
             break;
         }
    }
    return index;
}
```

}

I've been writing it for 2 days straight yet still can't understand how to sort a matrix.
Now when I add a player it knows how to put the ranks in the correct order, but now I need to write the find function which means to get the top 5 players in the specified Type(tokens[2]or player[index][1]; Now if I find a way to sort the players according to their ranks I might be able to pull it off. So the question is how to swap the places from getIndexPos(and the rest of the player array) and index. It seems like a complicated case I've never sorted in java before so I don't know anything about it. Is it possible?

Comment: So let me get this straight. You want to swap two rows of your matrix based on the two row indices?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I've used insertion sort this is the code:

```
public static String [][] sort(String [][] data,int count, int index){
    String tempName,tempType,tempAge,tempPos;

    for(int k=1;k<count;k++){
        String currentPos=data[k][3];
        tempName=data[k][0];
        tempAge=data[k][2];
        tempType=data[k][1];
        int j=k;
        while(j>0 && Integer.parseInt(data[j-1][3])>Integer.parseInt(currentPos)){
            data[j][3]=data[j-1][3];
            data[j][0]=data[j-1][0];
            data[j][1]=data[j-1][1];
            data[j][2]=data[j-1][2];
            j--;
        }
        data[j][3]=currentPos;
        data[j][0]=tempName;
        data[j][2]=tempAge;
        data[j][1]=tempType;
    }
    return data;
}
```